# Perform action on a button in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I've a UIButton in UITableViewCell...
I want to perform an action on the UIButton..

I need to send data to the @selector method that is registered for this button so that I can perform actions on when the user press this button.

How to accomplish that, though I found that the `(id) sender` parameter inside the selector function is not always the original button created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
UIImage* pdfImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_pdf.png"];
UIButton* pdfButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[pdfButton setImage:pdfImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
pdfButton.accessibilityHint = @"path/to/pdf/file";
pdfButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
[pdfButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openUrlInBrowser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = pdfButton;
```

Here's the sender function:

```
-(void) openUrlInBrowser:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [sender class]);
    NSString * url=[sender accessibilityHint];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

Comment: Do you want that button to cover the entire cell?

Comment: It would help to see the results of those NSLog statements. And the rest of your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping I understand correctly the question - I ususally define a tag on the button added in the uitableview which is the index of the row. In cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
[button setTag:indexPath.row];
```

You can then get it back in the target method :

```
- (void) showdatabases:(id) sender {
int row = [[sender valueForKey:@"tag"] intValue];
...
```

And query the values in the cell for your processing using :

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]];
```

Alternatively you could get the same result by accessing the superviews of the sender but I find this more difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use:

```
-(void) openUrlInBrowser:(id)sender
{
  UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
  NSString * url=[button.superview accessibilityHint];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

it not depend on cell position in the table

Comment: ok with your code, it is clear ! I have add an other solution